# Assign Parent ID to recursively called XML in VB.NET

Tags: xml, vb.net

Let's say I have 8 XML documents setup in the following manner.

**123.xml**

```
<link xlink="ABC">ABC</link>
<link xlink="DEF">DEF</link>
<link xlink="GHI">GHI</link>
```

**ABC.xml**

```
<link xlink="JKL">JKL</link>
```

**JKL.xml**

```
<link xlink="MNO">MNO</link>
```

**DEF.xml**

```
<link xlink="PQR">PQR</link>
```

**GHI.xml**

```
<link xlink="STU">STU</link>
```

**MNO.xml**, **PQR.xml** and **STU.xml** have no links.

I am moving through these files recursively using VB.NET starting with 123.xml and looking for xlink in each link tag.  For each xlink I then look for links in that document and so on until I run out and come back to the original document for the next xlink.

The order for the example above would be 123 -> ABC -> JKL -> MNO -> DEF -> PQR -> GHI -> STU.  There are multiple different ways these file structures could turn out, this is simply an example.

So if my code is similar to below and I am assigning an ID to each, just an integer that increments every time Add_Task is called, how would I go about finding out what the ID of the parent XML file is, the file that called the xlink originally?  Also any links in the first XML document (123.xml) should be give a parent ID of 0, since it is in the original document and doesn't have a parent.

```
Public Sub Get_Next_Link(filename as String)
    Dim xDoc As New XmlDocument()
    xDoc.Load(filename)

    Dim xNodeList As XmlNodeList = xDoc.SelectNodes("//link")

    For Each xNode as XMLNode in xNodeList
       Add_Task(ID, Name, ParentID)
       Get_Next_Link(get the xlink attribute and + ".xml" here)
    Next
End Sub
```

The Add_Task results of the above example should be as follows.

1, ABC, 0
2, JKL, 1
3, MNO, 2
4, DEF, 0
5, PQR, 4
6, GHI, 0
7, STU, 6

I'm having difficulties determining how to set/locate the parent ID of the link being processed.  If it helps, I am putting the results of the Add_Task method into a datatable.  I've tried calling the datatable with the previous link name (ABC, etc...) to get the ID but I am having issues where it is not giving me the correct parent ID so I am hoping that someone has a better method for accomplishing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your recursive method can leverage a parameter to help with this:

```
Public Sub Get_Next_Link(filename As String, level As Integer)
```

Then in the method increment as necessary:

```
level += 1

For Each xNode as XMLNode in xNodeList
   Add_Task(ID, Name, ParentID)
   Get_Next_Link("theNextFile.xml", level)
Next
```

The first time you call Get_Next_Link you should pass a value of -1 for this parameter for it to behave as you desire.

In terms of "setting the parentID", a DataTable can work, but maybe a simple custom class will suffice:

```
Public Class CustomXmlFile
    Public Property FileName As String
    Public Property ID As Integer
    Public Property ParentID As Integer
    'Etc
End Class
```

Then in your class where Get_Next_Link lives:

```
Private m_lstCustomXMLFiles As New List(Of CustomXmlFile)
```

Finally at the spot where you want to set the values (perhaps in Add_Task):

```
Dim objFile As New CustomXmlFile()
objFile.FileName = "Set your values"

m_lstCustomXMLFiles.Add(objFile)
```

Comment: This works up, but only up to a certain point.  It may be because I am omitting duplicate xlinks when they are found but here are my results of a test case (different than example).  The first instance in the original XML doc set the id/parent to 1/0, the first link set to 2/1, thumbs up.  Then there was a link off of ID 2 and it set it to 3/2, still good! Then 4/3, 5/4 and 6/4 as ID 4 had 2 links. Now I'm out of links for that chain. It goes back to ID 1 and finds 7/1, good! But here's where the wheels come off, the next one ID 8 should find 7 as it's parent but it finds 2 which is wrong.

Comment: This is a little tough to follow, but I would advise using the debugger at this point and stepping through the code to see where/why it breaks down.

Comment: Agreed, it's not the prettiest but these comment boxes aren't fantastic for posting follow-up results.  I've been going through the debugger to try to figure it out.  I'll set this as the answer as I think it's as close as I might get considering my question doesn't actually indicate duplicates being removed are a part of the issue.  Thanks for the push in the right direction!

Comment: After much testing and even allowing all duplicates to be entered this only ever gives you the tier that the item is on and never the actual ID of the parent.  The tier could be useful but I really need to know the ID of the parent link for each item added.

Comment: Instead of passing the tier as a parameter you can pass the parentId (or both if you need it).  Change your Add_Task to a function that returns the parentID so you can use it in your recursive call.

Comment: Right, I am actually doing that and have been from the start, but the problem is that I do not know what the parentID is for each item being passed.  That is what I have been trying to determine, what to pass for each item that when it is called again it knows that is the parentID.  I thought that it would just be the ID of the last item but with removing duplicate items it's not as simple as just passing the ID.

Answer (score 1):

Just pass the ID of the parent as parameter. In the example below, -1 would mean no parent.

```
Get_Next_Link("123.xml", -1)

Public Sub Get_Next_Link(filename as String, byval parentId as integer)

   ...

   Get_Next_Link(get the xlink attribute and + ".xml" here, ID)
```

---

Here's a move detailed example.

```
Module Module1

    Private DataInfo As New Dictionary(Of String, List(Of String))

    Sub Main()

        DataInfo.Add("123", New List(Of String) From {"ABC", "DEF", "GHI"})
        DataInfo.Add("ABC", New List(Of String) From {"JKL"})
        DataInfo.Add("JKL", New List(Of String) From {"MNO"})
        DataInfo.Add("DEF", New List(Of String) From {"PQR"})
        DataInfo.Add("GHI", New List(Of String) From {"STU"})

        Get_Next_Link("123", -1)

        Console.ReadLine()

    End Sub

    Private Sub Get_Next_Link(ByVal filename As String, ByVal parentID As Integer)

        Static nextAvailableId As Integer = 0
        Dim currentId As Integer = nextAvailableId

        nextAvailableId += 1

        Console.WriteLine(currentId & ", " & filename & ", " & parentID)

        If DataInfo.ContainsKey(filename) Then
            For Each link As String In DataInfo(filename)
                Get_Next_Link(link, currentId)
            Next
        End If

    End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: I have tried this and as per the comment in N0Alias's answer it doesn't flow properly.  I had originally tried this myself, passing the ID, but achieved incorrect results.

Comment: @RandyToye I added a more detailed answer with a complete example that returns the exact result you want. Instead of xml file I just did a dictionary of list.

Comment: thanks for the extra effort, I appreciate it.  My project is currently running out of time so I have shelved the recursion method on this one for now in favor of a slower but more accurate method.  I will likely come back to this once the users realize how slow this is and provide me with more hours!  This looks good though I can see how that would work.

Answer (score 0):

Using Linq :

```
Imports System.Data
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim dt As New DataTable()
        dt.Columns.Add("ID", GetType(Integer))
        dt.Columns.Add("Name", GetType(String))
        dt.Columns.Add("Parent_ID", GetType(Integer))

        dt.Rows.Add(New Object() {1, "ABC", 0})
        dt.Rows.Add(New Object() {2, "JKL", 1})
        dt.Rows.Add(New Object() {3, "MNO", 2})
        dt.Rows.Add(New Object() {4, "DEF", 0})
        dt.Rows.Add(New Object() {5, "PQR", 4})
        dt.Rows.Add(New Object() {6, "GHI", 0})
        dt.Rows.Add(New Object() {7, "STU", 6})

        Dim parent As String = GetParent("MNO", dt)


    End Sub

    Function GetParent(name As String, dt As DataTable) As String
        Dim parentID = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(Function(x) x.Field(Of String)("Name") = name).Select(Function(x) x.Field(Of Integer)("Parent_ID")).FirstOrDefault()

        Return dt.AsEnumerable().Where(Function(x) x.Field(Of Integer)("ID") = parentID).Select(Function(x) x.Field(Of String)("Name")).FirstOrDefault()
    End Function

End Module
```

Comment: Yes this would work great if I already knew the parent ID's, but I don't.  I am building the table as I recursively go through the XML documents and need to determine the parent of each new item as I get to it.

Comment: You are 99.99% of the way there.  You just need another parameter : Public Sub Get_Next_Link(filename as String, parentID as Integer)  The first call to the method the parentID will be zero.

Comment: @jdweng a big part of the question dealt with recursion in setting and getting the level of depth. You made a big assumption that it was already done. I'd say this alone would get 10% of the way there by itself :) consider borrowing the recursion part from N0Alias

Comment: I could of written the recursion, but the op already did that.  The only real issue was passing the parent ID to the child.  I have a million of my own recursion methods.  Don't need to borrow anything.

Comment: The issue still remains that I am unable to determine what it is that is the parentID, what exactly is the preceding XML document name for the current task being added.  I have tried using the previous ID but because I am excluding duplicates and other items the ID doesn't always work as the parentID, at least not the ways I have tried setting it.  I have no issues accessing the datatable to get information out, the issue I am having is setting the parentID in the first place.

Comment: You can only remove a duplicate if the parent id is the same.  Otherwise you could have a hanging object with no parent.

Comment: Which is my problem because the way the XML is setup (which is terrible and out of my control) I could have the same document show up, let's say MNO.xml could be a link off both ABC and DEF but in most instances I do not want MNO.xml to show up more than once.  In some instances I do want it to show up if it's a duplicate.  The reason for this is as follows.  The first document could tell me to "stop the car engine", somewhere else in the links it could also tell me to "stop the car engine", well I've already done that so I don't care.  Hope this helps to explain the reasons.

Comment: You have a graph.  The solution depends on the type of graph.  Not all graphs will work the same.  If your graph is truly a tree where paths diverge and never come back together you are ok.  If you have a non tree graph you can't get rid of the duplicates.

Comment: Ya I have another method that works for what I want it to do, I was just hoping that I could use recursion to eliminate some bad code.  Seems like it's just not meant to be.  Appreciate all the help from everyone on this one, I know it's not the greatest example and again the XML I'm using is terrible so that's not helpful.  Thanks again!